# Draw multiple canvases in SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

Can I use two or more canvases to draw in SurfaceView ?

For example

```
Canvas canvas1 = holder.lockCanvas;
canvas1.drawPath(path1, paint1);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas1);

Canvas canvas2 = holder.lockCanvas;
canvas2.drawPath(path2, paint2);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas2);
```

This code shows incorrect picture.

Comment: a list of `Canvas`es? what are they? they are not returned by `SurfaceHolder#lockCanvas()` ?

Comment: No I load it from file, but I can get pathes from canvas and use SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(), but in thet case to I don't know how to do that.

Comment: load from file? you load `Canvas`es from a file? how come?

Comment: I use svg library that get paths from svg file, it gave me paths and canvases that I can use.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: I edit my question, can you look to this code ?

Comment: same with this ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944843/is-it-possible-to-draw-on-multiple-canvases-at-once?rq=1]

Answer (score 1):

An Android Canvas is just a way to issue drawing commands. The SurfaceHolder hands you a Canvas that is only valid between the `lock()` and `unlockCanvasAndPost()` calls.

You're getting a different Canvas each time you lock the SurfaceHolder. SurfaceView is double- or triple-buffered, so you'll be rotating through a series of buffers as well.

Make sure you're not confusing the Android definition of "Canvas" with its use in other contexts.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I was drawing a line and circle with different lock for each and I noticed they start drawing together only after 2 calls. I only need a strategy to draw always between these two.